# How to Deploy Web Part from client to SharePoint Server (Different Machine)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint

I want to ask about Sharepoint 2013. I have a plan to deploy web part on my machine(client) to Sharepoint Server(different machine), client to server. is it possible? Because i only do remote dekstop to open visual studio and deploy web part.

Comment: Your english is too unclear to understand. As I understand you want to develop sharepoint webpart on the machine where there is not a sharepoint instance but only visual studio, and then you want to deploy that to your sharepoint server as .wsp?

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Getting Started (SharePoint Development in Visual Studio)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231568.aspx) before asking about sharepoint developing.